# how to use Polymer polyfills together

Tags: javascript, polyfills, polymer, shadow-dom

I'm trying to use the [Polymer](https://github.com/Polymer) polyfills for [ShadowDOM](https://github.com/Polymer/ShadowDOM) and [Custom Elements](https://github.com/Polymer/CustomElements)

If I use them individually, they work well, but when I use both at the same time I get errors like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'polymerShadowRoot_' of undefined.....Element.js:69
```

It depends whether I first include customelement.js or shadowdom.js

Here is my test code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>

    <script src="/bower_components/CustomElements/custom-elements.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/ShadowDOM/shadowdom.js"></script>

    <script>
      var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

      proto.createdCallback = function() {
        console.log('create shadowDOM');
        var root = this.createShadowRoot();
        root.innerHTML = '<content></content>';
      };

      document.register('x-foo', {prototype: proto});
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <x-foo><span>hallo</span></x-foo>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions what might go wrong here ?

Comment: This type of configuration should certainly be supported (please file a bug), but have tried using just platform.js to get the polyfill support? If that doesn't work with your code snippet, then it's truly a bug.

Comment: Can you create an isolated example on JSFiddle (or comparable site)?

Comment: When I replace the include of custom-elements.js and shadowdom.js with platform.js it works :)  Thnx. If I still need to prepare the above situation please let me know!

Comment: I also noticed that it doesn't work in PhantomJS, it throws the following error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Window\n
 at /Users/.../bower_components/platform/platform.js:29 Any suggestions how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever using ShadowDOM polyfill, you must load it first because it utterly remaps DOM. Other libraries (generally) can load on top of the remapping, but not underneath.

http://jsbin.com/uBOQIBu/3/edit